# ggarrange stretch ggplot object to occupy white space

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am trying plot `8` `ggplot objects` with `ggarrange` such that it plots `4` ggplot objects in each row. The code works fine, but now I am wanting the plot to be plotted in a way that the the plots occupy the extra white space between the label and the plot, for example the plot occupies the white space between label A and that plot, and so on for the rest of the plots. Basically, I want to stretch the plots, so all the space available in the grid is used. How can I do this?

```
gg.arrange = ggarrange(ggplot1,
                                  ggplot2,
                                  ggplot3,
                                  ggplot4,
                                  ggplot5,
                                  ggplot6,
                                  ggplot7,
                                  ggplot8,
                                  ncol = 4,
                                  nrow = 2,
                                  labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"),
                                  common.legend = TRUE,
                                  legend = "bottom")
```

Code for one of the ggplot objects:

```
ggplot1 = ggplot(shapefile_sf_object) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = Data), show.legend = T) + 
  coord_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = DEM_sf, aes(size = DEM), shape = 1, show.legend = T) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
  labs(title = "February", fill = "RMSE")
```

[image]

Comment: Could you share the code for one of the plots?

Comment: @zx8754, I have add the code for one of the plots as asked for.

Comment: Did you try to use other packages to put all plots together? patchwork, cowplot...

Comment: No I am not familiar with these packages; I will check them out. Cheers for sharing these.

Comment: Try to reduce the margin: `theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, "cm"))`

Comment: Did margins idea worked?

Comment: @zx8754, I did try it, but since I have a lot of ggplot objects, and one of them is a raster with thousands of pixels, so each time when I ran ggarrange for trying new margins, it took a lot of time. So, in the end I found a way that when I click on zoom in RStudio, the pop up window shows the plot with reduced margins, so I just saved that as an [image](https://app.box.com/s/30o5y15zovqgskptmrqxe95533boacvm). I know this might not be ideal, but it saved me a lot of time.

Comment: If your approach worked for you, please provide it as an answer below.

Comment: @zx8754, please feel free to edit my answer, as I am new to answering questions, and cheers on continued follow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way to reduce the margins, i.e. to minimize the space between the plot label and the plot itself. What I did was that once `ggarrange` displayed the plots in the plot section of RStudio.

I clicked on on the `Zoom` button, and the plots then got displayed in a popup window, which showed the plots with reduced space between the labels and the plots. And I believe, this can be further modified by adjusting the size of the popup window.

I used this approach, because I had a lot of plots in ggarrange, and one of these plots contained a raster with thousands of pixels, so each time I tried something different with the code, ggarrange took a lot of time, thus reducing the performance of my computer.

[image]